# Spring - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'form' available as request attribute

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm using **Java** and **Spring** using **Thymeleaf**.

I have created a form with a couple inputs, IntelliJ is moaning about it saying it cannot resolve the Thymeleaf object attribute. When I try to load the website it gives error code 500.

I have tried a lot of the common issues online like missing the xmlns:th in the HTML tag, I've played endlessly around with changing tiny little things from old versions. Not quite sure what to do anymore I've been to the end of the internet and back but maybe I'm being stupid.
Here is the stack:

```
2023-09-22T21:20:01.188+01:00 ERROR 15828 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'form' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:232) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractElementTagProcessor.process(AbstractElementTagProcessor.java:95) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.util.ProcessorConfigurationUtils$ElementTagProcessorWrapper.process(ProcessorConfigurationUtils.java:633) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.ProcessorTemplateHandler.handleStandaloneElement(ProcessorTemplateHandler.java:918) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(TemplateHandlerAdapterMarkupHandler.java:260) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler$InlineMarkupAdapterPreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:256) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.standard.inline.OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(OutputExpressionInlinePreProcessorHandler.java:169) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.handleStandaloneElementEnd(InlinedOutputExpressionMarkupHandler.java:104) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlVoidElement.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlVoidElement.java:92) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.HtmlMarkupHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(HtmlMarkupHandler.java:297) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupEventProcessorHandler.handleOpenElementEnd(MarkupEventProcessorHandler.java:402) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.ParsingElementMarkupUtil.parseOpenElement(ParsingElementMarkupUtil.java:159) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseBuffer(MarkupParser.java:710) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:301) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257) ~[attoparser-2.0.7.RELEASE.jar:2.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1103) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1077) ~[thymeleaf-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:372) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring6.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:192) ~[thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1415) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1159) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1098) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.13.jar:10.1.13]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

As I saw that it saying its struggling to link between the form and mapping in the controller.
I have played around with the controller changing things like adding `model.addAttribute("form", new Form());` however this does not fix it. I have `@ModelAttribute("form")`.

I have also tried looking for an annotation to add in Form.java which is my object it needs to bind too.

This is my HTML in my template, index.html. This is where IntelliJ has got orange moan lines under `${form}` and red ones under; `*{name}`, `*{email}`, `*{message}`. I have attempted a few things like having `<form:form hidde..` and also that with `th:`, Not quite sure if the issue is here or not.

```xml
    <div class="grid-item" id="content-box">
        <noscript><p style="color: #ffffff; text-align: center">You do not have Javascript enabled. It is required for this website to work correctly.</p></noscript>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <form hidden id="form" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${form}">
            <p class="text">Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"></p>
            <p class="text">Email: <input type="text" th:field="*{email}"></p>
            <p class="text">Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{message}"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

As said before with my FormController, I have changed some things, I tried switching from `PostMapping()` to `RequestMapping()` and then adding `modelAttribute="form"` in there but that doesn't work either.
I also added `model.addAttribute("form", new Form())` as someone said that fixes it, however it is still happening.

```java
@Controller
public class FormController {
    @PostMapping("/form")
    public void formReceived(@ModelAttribute("form") Form form, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("form", new Form());
        System.out.println(form.getName());
    }
}
```

Finally the last link which I can think of is my form class however I don't see where it could of gone wrong, I have tried searching through the annotations too see if there is anything I can add, but I haven't found one.

```java
public class Form {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String message;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

So yeah.. I'm not sure where to go here, there are a lot of similar things on here but they are all from 2016 and have like 1 one response, which is where I got many of these little fixes but they haven't worked for what I suspect is them being really old.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had a separate FormController class with my mapping in it,
In my main mapping for the "/" endpoint which the website was on I added: `model.addAttribute("form", new Form());` and exposed it as in the FormController it wasn't exposing it.